# function that selects the largest record from a table in mariaDb

Tags: mariadb

I need to create a function in the mariaDb database, which will take two parameters, the name of the table and the name of the column, and should return the highest value of this field in the given table.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION `getMax`(`cTable` VARCHAR(255), `cColumn` VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE nMax INT;
    SET nMax = 0;
    SELECT MAX(`cColumn`) INTO nMax FROM `cTable`;
    RETURN nMax;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm creating the function, but when I use it I get the following error:

```
Erro SQL (1146): Table 'db.cTable' doesn't exist
```

How do I replace the parameter name with the value in my select?

Comment: For this you need dynamic sql

Comment: Also limitations exist like [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE not allowed in Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/), I tried a procedural form which failed. [MDEV-32922](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32922). I'd save stored procedures and functions for more complicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

you need a stored procedure to do that weil we can not use dynamixc sql in Functions.

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists getMax_sp$$
CREATE procedure getMax_sp(cTable VARCHAR(255), cColumn VARCHAR(255), out nMax int)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL= concat('select max(', cColumn, ') INTO @nMax from ', cTable);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    set nMax=@nMax;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

to use it:

```
call getMax_fn('MyTableName', 'MyColumnName', @MaxN);
select @MaxN;
```